# unable to echo message sent in html page using php

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I currently have this page I am working on:
http://www.webauthorsgroup.com/new/template/index3.html

In the lower right corner is a form (php), but I can't "echo" a text message after it has been submitted (for whatever reason).

My form is:

```
<form id="contact" method="post" action="">
<fieldset>  

<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" title="Enter your name" class="required">

<label for="email">E-mail</label>
<input name="hidden" class="required email" onblur="if(value=='<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['email']); ?>') value = 'Your Email'" onfocus="if(value=='Your Email') value = ''" type="email" value="Your Email" placeholder="yourname@domain.com">

<label for="phone">Phone</label>
<input name="phone" onblur="if(value=='<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['phone']); ?>') value = 'phone'" onfocus="if(value=='phone') value = ''" type="tel" value="phone" placeholder="ex. (555) 555-5555">
<input type="hidden" name="phone" placeholder="ex. (555) 555-5555">

<label for="message">Question/Comment</label>
<textarea name="message" onblur="if(value=='<?php echo htmlentities($_POST['message']); ?>') value = 'message'" onfocus="if(value=='message') value = ''" value="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit" value="Send Message" />

</fieldset>
</form>
```

=========================================================

the process.php is:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

// Get Data 
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
$url = strip_tags($_POST['url']);
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
echo "Thank You!";
}
// Send Message
mail( "bruce@webauthorsgroup.com", "Inquiry From WebAuthorsGroup",
"Name: $name\nEmail: $email\nPhone: $phone\nWebsite: $url\nMessage: $message\n",
"From: Forms <forms@example.net>" );
?>
```

=================================================

I need the "message sent" text echoed in the same div after submitting the form and I don't want to convert my index page to index.php

Any help would be great!

Comment: Your form is missing the `action` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code on the page index3.html is not being parsed or executed by the PHP interpreter on your server because the file extension is .html. Go ahead and view source on that page in the browser. Note that you can see the PHP code. You should not be able to see PHP code in the HTML source. You should see only the HTML rendered by the PHP. Please change the file extension to .php so your server can execute it instead of outputting it as text.